# packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: ubuntu

**How can I fix the dependency problems?**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  gcc-4.4: Depends: gcc-4.4-base (= 4.4.7-1ubuntu2) but 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 is installed
           Depends: cpp-4.4 (= 4.4.7-1ubuntu2) but 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 is installed
           Depends: binutils (>= 2.20.1-15~) but 2.20.1-3ubuntu7.2 is installed
           Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.4.7-1ubuntu2) but 1:4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 is installed
           Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.21 is installed
           Recommends: libc6-dev (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6) but 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.21 is installed
  libapt-inst1.4: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.21 is installed
  libapt-pkg4.12: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.21 is installed
                  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 is installed
  libc6: Depends: libc-bin (= 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.21) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.11 is installed
  libgomp1: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.21 is installed
  libnih-dbus1: Depends: libnih1 (= 1.0.3-4ubuntu9.1) but 1.0.1-1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

**On Ubuntu Server:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release:    10.04
Codename:   lucid
```

**I want update Unbuntu from 10.04 to 14.04 with command: do-release-upgrade**

```
                ERROR:root:got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'libnih-dbus1': 'dependency problems - leaving unconfigured'
                                                                                                                       No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                    ERROR:root:got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'libgomp1': 'dependency problems - leaving unconfigured'
                                                                                                                       No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                                                     ERROR:root:got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'gcc-4.4': 'dependency problems - leaving unconfigured'
                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                        endency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgomp1:
 libgomp1 depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
  Version of libc6 on system is 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.21.
dpkg: error processing libgomp1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gcc-4.4:
 gcc-4.4 depends on gcc-4.4-base (= 4.4.7-1ubuntu2); however:
  Version of gcc-4.4-base on system is 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1.
 gcc-4.4 depends on cpp-4.4 (= 4.4.7-1ubuntu2); however:
  Version of cpp-4.4 on system is 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1.
 gcc-4.4 depends on binutils (>= 2.20.1-15~); however:
  Version of binutils on system is 2.20.1-3ubuntu7.2.
 gcc-4.4 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.4.7-1ubuntu2); however:
  Version of libgcc1 on system is 1:4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1.
 gcc-4.4 depends on libgomp1 (>= 4.4.7-1ubuntu2); however:
  Package libgomp1 is not configured yet.
 gcc-4.4 depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
  Version of libc6 on system is 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.21.
dpkg: error processing gcc-4.4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapt-pkg4.12
 libapt-inst1.4
 libnih-dbus1
 libgomp1
 gcc-4.4
Exception during pm.DoInstall():  E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ERROR:root:Exception during pm.DoInstall()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpyDUDjM/DistUpgradeView.py", line 203, in run
    res = pm.do_install(self.writefd)
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ERROR:root:installArchives returned 'installArchives() failed'
WARNING:root:_fetchArchives for backports returned False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpyDUDjM/precise", line 3, in <module>
    from DistUpgradeMain import main
  File "/tmp/tmpyDUDjM/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 25, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/release-upgrader-python-apt/apt/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12)
=== Command detached from window (Sun Mar  1 13:07:39 2015) ===
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Sun Mar  1 13:07:39 2015) ===
```

Comment: why post this here and not in Ask Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Directly upgrading from 10.04 to 14.04 is not a supported upgrade path, you should go from 10.04 to 12.04 and then to 14.04.